# sbt 1.6.2: `java.io.IOException: Function not implemented`

Tags: docker, scala, sbt

With the Dockerfile:

```
FROM sbtscala/scala-sbt:11.0.15_1.6.2_2.12.15 as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY build.sbt ./
COPY src ./src

RUN sbt package
```

I run:

```bash
docker build --platform linux/amd64 --no-cache -t test-app .
```

I get:

```
> [builder 5/5] RUN sbt package:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#11 13.75 [info] Updated file /app/project/build.properties: set sbt.version to 1.6.2                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#11 13.85 [info] welcome to sbt 1.6.2 (Oracle Corporation Java 11.0.15)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#11 24.90 [info] loading project definition from /app/project                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
#11 49.28 [info] loading settings for project app from build.sbt ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#11 50.76 [info] set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/app/)
#11 50.87 java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
#11 50.88   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.<init>(LinuxWatchService.java:64)
#11 50.88   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.newWatchService(LinuxFileSystem.java:47)
...
#11 50.89   at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
#11 51.01 [error] java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
#11 51.01 [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
#11 51.04 [warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
```

This is using the `build.sbt` and `SimpleApp.scala` given on the Spark 3.3.0 quick start: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

I'm trying to use Scala 2.12.15 + JDK 11.x that matches the official `apache/spark:v3.3.0` docker image.

This is a super simple sbt build with the official image. Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: I can't reproduce on a Linux VM. I suppose you are running the `docker` command on an ARM machine (Mac M1) since you specified `--platform linux/amd64`. I guess the error could be related to this: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6174. `LinuxWatchService.java` uses `inotify`: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/linux/classes/sun/nio/fs/LinuxWatchService.java#L55. If you confirm that you are running the `docker` command from an ARM machine, I will change this comment to an answer to help other people facing that kind of issues.

Comment: Yes, I'm using docker on an ARM machine, M1 Mac.

Comment: Ok, then it's a known issue: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/ (`In addition, filesystem change notification APIs (inotify) do not work under qemu emulation`).

Comment: Does sbt works outside Docker? It would be worth creating an issue on sbt repo I guess.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am able to make sbt work as expected outside the container. I am using podman, so same error there too. I am using sbt 1.7.0 by the way.